# Team Foundation Server: Assign work item to a group instead of an individual user

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2010, is there a way that I can assign a work item to a group (i.e. Developers or Designers) instead of an individual user? I'd also want to be able to create a query so that we can filter on that group as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. If your group is a member of the larger group that can be assigned to, then it will appear in the list of assignable users.

For example, a user hierarchy might be like this:

```
[Assignable Users]
  [Developers]
  [Project Managers]
  Mark Avenius
  Joe Schmoe
```

**EDIT**
As for the query, you can have the clause `Assigned To` contains `@Me`, which I believe will do what you want.

Comment: @Mark Avenius - is it possible to assign a User Story/Task to a team [Group] in VSTS?