# In VSTS, is it possible to assign a Feature/User Story/Task to a team [Group]

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops

In VSTS, My project got different teams/areas as shown here

[image: Project Teams]

[image: Areas]

Is it possible to assign a Feature/User Story/Task to a team [Group]? I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821877/team-foundation-server-assign-work-item-to-a-group-instead-of-an-individual-use#) w.r.to TFS, but couldn't accomplish in VSTS.

I've got requirement like assigning a task [Meetings/KT/stand-up call/..] to group/groups rather than individuals.Could someone help on this? Thank you

Comment: Looks like this one was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717552/can-i-assign-a-work-item-to-a-group-in-visual-studio-team-services-previously-v

Comment: Provided solution [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/work/scale/portfolio-management) contains screenshots/working in TFS, not in VSTS. I've gone through this already but doesn't solve my issue

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish? Work items are not completed by a team, they are completed by an individual. Putting a work item in the team's area path indicates that the work item is the team's responsibility to assign to an individual to be completed.

Comment: @Daniel Mann - I got your point. But how do we capture common team tasks like KT/Scrum calls/Meeting's in VSTS. In case if we can't capture, its gonna effect capability index/availability index of the team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot assign an work item to multiple[Group/Team]. Microsoft has not considered this yet, find the link below

[Assign a Work Item to Multiple [Group/Team]](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2358861-assign-a-work-item-to-multiple-people)

In Case you need to point a work item to any single/specific team, you could do that by mapping the Area Path field to that specific Single team[Can't map to multiple teams].

Comment: Does mapping Area Path, reflect/consume timelines/availability index of the team members?

Comment: No it doesn't reflect/Consume availability index

Answer (score 2):

No, it’s impossible to assign work item to a team/group.

You can find in the document [Assign work items to a team member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/about-work-items#assign-work-items-to-a-team-member), it mentions a work item  can only be assigned to one member:

> You can only assign a work item to one person at a time. The Assigned
> To field is person-name field designed to hold an account identity
> recognizable by VSTS or TFS.
>
> - You can assign a work item to one and
>   only one team member at a time. If work is split across two or more
>   team members, then you should consider creating additional work items
>   that you'll assign to each member responsible for the work to be
>   completed

Comment: Got it,Thanks for your clarification/answer. How do we capture common team tasks like KT/Scrum calls/Meeting's in VSTS. In case if we can't capture, its gonna effect capability index/availability index of the team. Please suggest on this

Comment: You can use Area field to assitent t=your requirement.

Comment: I suppose, you are mentioning about Area Path field in work item. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it's Aera path.